# Put JSON data with the same name into different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have JSON file with this structure:

```js
{
  "launches": [{
    "name": "First Name"
  }],
  "launches": [{
    "name": "Second Name"
  }],
  "launches": [{
    "name": "Third Name"
  }],
  "launches": [{
    "name": "Fourth Name"
  }]
}
```

I add the data like this:

```js
$('#div-name').append(d.name);
```

When this is displayed on a webpage, it is placed in one div with no spaces. I can add a `<p>` tag to the append, but that still displays ALL the data and creates new divs to display it.

Basically, what I am trying to do is to create a div for each separate "name" value and *display only one value per div*.

Comment: That JSON exactly depicts what JSON shouldn't be used for.

Comment: The syntax of your object in the first example is invalid as, aside from the lack of quotes around the strings, you cannot have duplicate property names. If you need this kind of data structure put an array in a single property. Then it's a simple process to loop through that array

Comment: I think I oversimplified my example - The JSON I am using is from here: [link] (https://launchlibrary.net/1.2/launch/next/5). The name property is placed in the launches array.

Comment: I suspect you mis-copied your json. That json would not have the result you've described. Can you provide actual json (in your question) along with a full code sample we can test? html included?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your "json" **is not a valid json**, remmeber that in a json object, you can not have duplicated keys. You can easily use [an online validator](https://jsonlint.com/) to help you with that... and after you fix it, let's assume that what you actually have is an array of objects like:

```
[
    {"name": "Falcon 9"},
    {"name": "Orion"},
    {"name": "PSLV"},
    {"name": "Soyuz"}
]
```

with this valid json, you can easily loop trough all the elements like (and take that you are using jQuery):

```
var json = [ ... ];

$(function() {
    $.each(json, function(i, item){
        $("p").append("<div>" + item.name + "</div>");
    });
});
```

here's a live test: https://jsbin.com/bixadegeye/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I believe `Array.forEach` bypasses the need to load jQuery.

Comment: @FreemanLambda in his question, he already uses jQuery ... only because of that, and if he has issues even to know what a valid json object looks like, I assumed to stay in jQuery for the sake of simplicity...

Comment: Validators have caught my mistakes on many occasions. Thanks @balexandre

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different way of going about it:

```
var data = {
  "names": [
    "Falcon 9",
    "Orion",
    "PSLV",
    "Soyuz"
  ]
};

$.each( data["names"], function( key, value ) {
    $('#div-name').append(value+"<br />");
});
```